# Polygon function in GDI

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

I am trying to create a program that draws triangles/various polygons to the window on mouse click. I have the application drawing to the window but I cannot get them to repaint when the window is invalidated.

I've just tried to include the important part of the code.

The temp triangle will be made bigger/smaller when the user moves the mouse. When they let go of the left mouse button the triangle is stored in the struct. This part seems to work fine and each triangle's information is stored. Baring in mind I am not currently using thickness or the colours in the struct.

```
typedef struct
{

POINT pt[3];
unsigned int colour1;
unsigned int colour2;
unsigned int colour3;
unsigned int thickness;
unsigned int printOrder;

}Triangles;

Triangles temp_tri;
Triangles triangle_store[MAX_OBJECTS];
int triCount = 0;

case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:

if(triButtonPressed) //Faulty Feature
    {
        mouse_down_x = LOWORD(lParam);
        mouse_down_y = HIWORD(lParam);

        temp_tri.pt[0].x = mouse_down_x;
        temp_tri.pt[0].y = mouse_down_y;

        mouse_down = true;

    }

case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
if(triButtonPressed)
    {
        if(mouse_down)
        {
            temp_tri.pt[1].x= LOWORD(lParam);
            temp_tri.pt[1].y = HIWORD(lParam);
            temp_tri.pt[2].x= LOWORD(lParam) *2;
            temp_tri.pt[2].y= HIWORD(lParam) *2;

            InvalidateRect(hWnd,NULL,true);
        }
    }

case WM_LBUTTONUP:
else if(triButtonPressed)
    {
        temp_tri.pt[1].x = LOWORD(lParam);
        temp_tri.pt[1].y = HIWORD(lParam);
        temp_tri.pt[2].x= LOWORD(lParam) + 90;
        temp_tri.pt[2].y = HIWORD(lParam) + 90;
        printOrder++;
        temp_tri.printOrder = printOrder;
        triangle_store[triCount] = temp_tri;
        triCount ++;
        mouse_down = false;
    }

case WM_PAINT:

for(int  i =0; i<triCount; i++)
        {

            if(o == triangle_store[i].printOrder)
            {

                rePaintTriangles(backDC);
            }
        }

if(triButtonPressed)
    {
        if(mouse_down)
        {
            triangle(backDC);
        }
    }


void triangle(HDC hdc)
{

POINT pt[3];

pt[0].x = temp_tri.pt[0].x;
pt[0].y = temp_tri.pt[0].y; //Works fine. 
pt[1].x = temp_tri.pt[1].x;
pt[1].y = temp_tri.pt[1].y;
pt[2].x = temp_tri.pt[2].x;
pt[2].y = temp_tri.pt[2].y;

Polygon(hdc,pt,3);
}

void rePaintTriangles(HDC hdc)
{


Polygon(hdc,triangle_store[triCount].pt,3); //Doesn't Work

}
```

Comment: what is variable `o` used for the test in `WM_PAINT`?

Answer (score 0):

When you receive a WM_PAINT message, you're supposed to call [`BeginPaint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the HDC into which you should be painting.

Comment: ...and when you're done, `EndPaint` to tell it the formerly invalid rectangle is now valid.